# Resetting password does not work

Tags: php, mysql

I got a irritating problem, I can set a new user + password. Logging in works perfectly. When I reset the password, should be the same code, I am not able to log in with the new password, and I can't log in with the old password.

Code for setting new user:

```
$random_salt = hash('sha512', uniqid(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16), TRUE));
$password = hash('sha512', $clientPassword . $random_salt);

$stmt->bind_param('ssssssssss', $clientID,$clientName,$clientCompany,
          $clientPassword,$clientEmail,$random_salt,$clientAddress,
          $clientBilling,$clientNotes,$clientTel);
$stmt->execute();
```

Code für updating password:

```
$query = "UPDATE managerClients SET password = ? , salt = ? WHERE id = ?";


if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)) 
{   
$random_salt = hash('sha512', uniqid(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16), TRUE));
$password = hash('sha512', $clientPassword . $random_salt);

$stmt->bind_param('sss', $password, $random_salt, $userID);
$stmt->execute();
}
```

Before I send the password via ajax:

```
password:hex_sha512(password)
```

Has anyone got an idea what could create this problem ?

Comment: SHA512 is too fast for passwords.  Use bcrypt or PBKDFv2.

Comment: Is the data updated in the table? If so, is the new password correctly hashed?

Comment: yes the data is updated in the table both salt and password